# In ffmpeg, how to keep SDL output realtimely for the live-view?

Tags: display, ffmpeg, delay, sdl

When used alone in ffmpeg command line, SDL provide exellent live-view display with nearly no delay in video stream except for audio stream.
like this.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080  -rtbufsize 2G -framerate 59.94 -i "Directshow A/V capture devices" -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -window_size qcif -f sdl "SDL OUT"
```

But when used together with other outputs, i.e., in the multiple outputs case,  SDL output displayed significantly big delay, up to 5 seconds or more.
for example, I tried to display the input video stream realtimely by SDL and encoding input and save it as below ffmpeg commands set. but SDL output display was delayed significantly.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080  -rtbufsize 2G -framerate 59.94 -i "Directshow A/V capture devices" \
        -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -window_size qcif -f sdl "SDL OUT" \
        -c:v h264_qsv -preset fast -profile:v high  -b:v 7500k -trellis:v P -r 30 -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -strict experimental -y -f mpegts d:\test.ts
```

Isn't there any way to keep SDL output display realtimely ?

how can I keep monitoring captured input video realtimely by SDL and encode & save it simultaneously ?
thanks in advance.